# Fubini: Exchange of Expectation & Riemann Integration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Suppose a process $X_t$ is defined as follows for some $H(\omega,t)$:

$$X_t:=\int_{s=0}^{s=t}H(\omega,s)ds$$

Suppose we want to compute the expectation of $X_t$:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_t]=\int_{\Omega}\int_{s=0}^{s=t}H(\omega,s)dsd\mathbb{P}$$

One way to interpret Fubini's theorem is to argue that we can exchange the order of integration above as long as:

- (i) $\mathbb{E}[|H(\omega,t)|]<\infty$
- (ii) $H(\omega,t)$ is measurable

**I would like to ask about condition (ii) (i.e. "measurability"): suppose we want to apply Fubuni to the following examples, how do we check or demonstrate the measurability condition in practice?**

$$\tag{1} X_t:=\int_{s=0}^{s=t}W_s^2ds$$

$$\tag{2} X_t:=\int_{s=0}^{s=t}W_t^2ds$$

$$\tag{3} X_t:=\int_{s=0}^{s=t}\left(W_1(s)+W_2(s)\right)ds$$

**Question (1)**: This expectation is easily computable ( $\mathbb{E}[X_t]=\int \mathbb{E}[W_s^2]ds = \int s ds=0.5s^2$), but **how do I check the measurability condition if I have to?** I suppose my entire probability space would be generated by the Weiener measure associated with $W_t$, so I would just have to "show" that $W_t$ is measurable w.r.t. the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ (which it actually generates): so could I just say that "by definition of the probability space, the integrand is measurable"?

**Question (2)**: here the integrand is $W_t$ (i.e. the Wiener process at time $t$), whilst the integral runs from $s=0$ to $s=t$: **is the integrand measurable (with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ ?) ??** How do I show it is / show it isn't? Can the expectation be put inside the integral?

**Question (3)**: Again, **how do I show the integrand is measurable?** Similarly to (1), here the probability measure is generated by the set of two Brownian motions (correlated with $\rho t$), so simply by definition of the probability space, the integrand is measurable (with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ ? ) ?

Comment: In $(2)$ the wiener process does not depend on $s$ so you can pull it out of the integral, and hence you obtain $W_t^2 t$ which is clearly measurable w.r.t $F_t$.

Comment: @Chaos: thank you. And for the other two, does it suffice to say something along the lines that "by definition of the probability space, the integrand is measurable, because it generates the probability space" ?

Comment: in condition $(ii)$ what do you mean by "measurable" (namely w.r.t which sigma algebra)? I mean in $(1)$, $W_s^2$ is obviously measurable in the probability space where it lives, is also measurable with respect to $F_s$, I don't know if I am missing something though

Comment: @Chaos: "What is meant by 'measurable' " is actually what I am wondering myself, with regards to being able to apply the Fubini's theorem. Those two conditions (i) and (ii) are the conditions I have commonly come across, but I wonder myself what exactly is meant by condition (ii)? I suppose measurablity with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the only measurability that makes sense...

Comment: I imagine the measurability must be understood w.r.t the sigma algebra in your probability space.

Comment: $(\omega,t)\mapsto W(\omega,t)$ is clearly measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of the underlying prob. space.